# How to reduce the complexity of counting filters applied to an inventory

Tags: elasticsearch, caching, logic, time-complexity

If we have an inventory system where stocks are inserted, deleted and updated on daily basis. and the user can filter the inventory on multiple category. what would be the best approach to return the count of stocks based on the filters applied. Should we pre-compute all possible filter and store it in cache whenever a new stock is added/deleted/updated , which i believe will be wrong as there can be n! possible filter combination and storing them will be waste. or should we only compute the most used filters and update them.
Please note we do use elasticsearch so it does internally cache applied filters.

Comment: I presume the inventory stats are needed on-demand and ES aggregations are pretty fast, even after a "cold start" with newly added/updated docs... So what does your typical query look like? How long does it take as of now?

Comment: This sounds more like a database question.  In such context, "Complexity" questions are overshadowed by "index" and "IOPs" questions.